# How to retrieve decimal value from Integer?

Tags: java, android, integer, decimal

I'm trying to calculate the average based on user input. Now I've got the basics working, but I am only getting whole numbers as result. I want decimal numbers like 5.5

Any explanation is welcome!

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView);
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average);
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton);

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new  View.onClickListener() {
     @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")
     public void onClick(View v) { 

int grade[] = {Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString());

int weight[] = {Integer.parseInt(((EditText)  findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString());

int weightTotal = weight[0];

int sum = grade[0] * weight[0]

int average = sum / weightTotal


averageView.setText(averageText + Integer.toString(average));
```

**EDIT:**

I have experimented with a answer and got a solution for my problem.

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView);
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average);
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton);

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new  View.onClickListener() {
     @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")
     public void onClick(View v) { 

double grade[] = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString());

double weight[] = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText)  findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString());

double weightTotal = weight[0];

double sum = grade[0] * weight[0]

double average = sum / weightTotal


averageView.setText(averageText + " " + Double.toString(average));
```

Comment: Your expression seems like always give integer value. So why do you need to show as float?

Comment: I want to display the average of grades. Usually this is displayed like 5.5, 9.5, 7.0. And the user input will likely also be like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok You can do it like this**

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView);
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average);
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton);

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new  View.onClickListener() {
 @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")
 public void onClick(View v) { 

int grade = {Integer.parseInt(((EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString());

int weight = {Integer.parseInt(((EditText)  
findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString());

double sum = grade * weight

double average = sum / weight


averageView.setText(averageText +" "+ average);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The division operator / means integer division if there is an integer
>   on both sides of it. If one or two sides has a floating point number,
>   then it means floating point division. The result of integer division
>   is always an integer. Integer division determines how many times one
>   integer goes into another. The remainder after integer division is
>   simply dropped, no matter how big it is.

Change the type of variable average to float and typecast one of the sum or weight to float:

```
float average = (float)sum / weightTotal;
```

Also change `Integer.toString(average)` to `Float.toString(average)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting integers because you are only using integers !!.

That's normal, If you like average as decimal you have to declare it as `Float` or `Double` instead of `int`.

Note that even if you use such casting (Float.parseFloat....) it wont work because the variable average can only hold integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
float x = (float) y / z

text.setText("your avarage is : " + x );
```

also you should use try/catch while get data from edittext for convert Integer. otherwise you can get crash